# Web library to represent a Minecraft item (image + name + lore + all data)

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript

I'm looking for a web library able to represent a Minecraft item like in-game (small image for the icon, and hover text with all the information such as name, lore, enchantments, ...).

To give a little more context, I'm doing a web application for my server's moderators and administrators to allow them to see and modify (at least remove illegal items) from player's inventory / enderchest / any other storage source. I have all the needed data (NBT-serialized items) and I'm trying to display them.

Ideally, a React library would be awesome, but obviously I can work with any JS/HTML/CSS library to build my app with.

My research gave me the following results:

1. https://www.gamergeeks.net/apps/minecraft/web-developer-tools/css-blocks-and-entities
2. https://github.com/1e4/minecraft-items-css
3. https://codepen.io/devbobcorn/pen/wvzxxLv
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sfirew/mc-motd-parser/v/1.0.3

Both 1. and 2. are only about item icons (inserting the image from the ID), the first one seems to have a few less images (no potion color variants) but has a JSON "database" to lookup CSS classes from Minecraft IDs, and the second one seems to have more images, but no real mapping.

And 3. is a showcase of a hover bubble that looks like in-game ones.

Link 4. seems to deal with JSON text format but is a bit weird.

That's quite a lot of things to bring together to get a kind of workaround. Moreover, some items have a texture that depends on their NBT tags (like the aforementioned potion color) so only relying on item IDs seems insufficient. This confirms my question about a library being able to handle full item NBT data (maybe in a JSON format because it would be easier to manipulate in JS) to generate the display.

While I could develop my own library to do this, I would like to know if something already exists before reinventing the wheel. It would save me a lot of time.